# OpenApi Swagger generate Java RestTemplate client

Tags: spring, jersey, resttemplate, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I'm using Openapi 3 to generate java http client.

In my maven plugin configuration, I'm using "resttemplate" :

[image]

So I was expecting as a result Spring `RestTemplate` classes to make HTTP calls.

But in generated sources, I got `ApiClient` class to handle HTTP calls. `ApiClient` comes from Jersey library. There's no mention about Spring `RestTemplate` classes :

[image]

Is this normal ?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation at this link: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/spring.md

Search for the `library` config option in the big table, and you'll see that the two choices for the `library` config option are `spring-boot` or `spring-cloud`. You're using `resttemplate`, which is not valid.

(You're using version 5.1.0 of the generator, I'm using 5.0.0, but I'm pretty sure the link I provided applies to both.)

Comment: He's using the java generator, not the spring one. So resttemplate is a valid library option (spring/spring-cloud applies to spring generator, not java)

https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/java/